# Bind value to NSUserDefaults with Suite in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, swift, interface-builder, nsuserdefaults, xib

Is it possible to bind user interface elements (for example, a NSTextField) to `NSUserDefaults` with a [SuiteName](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1409957-initwithsuitename) in Interface Builder? I am attempting to do this in order to share user defaults between a widget app extension and main application with [App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW61).

I am currently doing this in code by reading from a `NSUserDefaults` object that I've instantiated:

```m
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.joshparnham.AppName"]
```

and then manually setting the value of all of my UI elements in code.

This question was asked on the [Cocoa-dev mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2015/Aug/msg00041.html) but didn't receive a response.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest building and viewModel with a constructor. Initialising that view model and either passing that To a viewController and manually bind the values or create a UIView for that VM and bind the values in the view